# Android Studio Jellyfish Terminal Characters Spacing Problem

Tags: android-studio

I have updated my android studio to the latest version of **Jelly Fish Canary 9** which arose in error of the terminal text characters spacing as shown in the image which seems so disturbing for me. I can't find any solution except for updating Android Studio. Let me know if there is any solution or any one else experienced the same problem with any older version.

I tried updating the Android Studio from Canary 7 version to Canary 9 Version and I also restarted the Android Studio again and again but the problem doesn't vanishes.

**Here is the Image of my Terminal:**
[image]

Comment: If someone has found the solution to this problem please guide me to solve the problem. This large spacing of the terminal is disgusting for me.